# How to invoke ApplicationContextInitializer in junit of spring-boot application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I am new to spring-boot and implemented a simple application with dynamic entity filtering based on [squiggly](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly-filter-jackson). Everything works fine except I am unable to make a junit to test that functionality. I tested a lot of solutions found on the web but none works.

My application is initialized as proposed in squiggly documentation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean squigglyRequestFilter() {
     FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
     filter.setFilter(new SquigglyRequestFilter());
     filter.setOrder(1);
     return filter;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new MyApplicationContextInitializer().initialize(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args));
   }
}

public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        //context.refresh()
        Iterable<ObjectMapper> objectMappers = context.getBeansOfType(ObjectMapper.class).values();

        Squiggly.init(objectMappers, new RequestSquigglyContextProvider());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Iterables.getFirst(objectMappers, null);

        // Enable Squiggly for Jackson message converter
        if (objectMapper != null) {
            for (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter : context.getBeansOfType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class).values()) {
                converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test I implemented:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = MyApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SimpleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testEntityFiltering() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/issues").param("fields", "id"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            // There should be only one field in the returned objects
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].length()").value(1));
    }
}
```

When I run that test I get the following exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@4116aac9 has not been refreshed yet
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1067) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1187) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at com.renault.api.examples.springboot.MyApplicationContextInitializer.initialize(MyApplicationContextInitializer.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:567) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

If I uncomment the line //context.refresh in MyApplicationContextInitializer.initialize I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(GenericApplicationContext.java:263) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120) ~[spring-boot-test-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

If remove the @ContextConfiguration annotation, the test fails because the entity filter is not installed.

It seems Stackoverflow is my last chance to get this working ...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but you can try to put context.initializer.classes=your.package.MyApplicationContextInitializer in src/test/resources/application.properties

Comment: Didn't help in my case.